# Capturing LTE(?) voice packets with Shark for Root

Tags: applications

I have a Samsung Galaxy Note 3 LTE. I installed Shark for Root but it only captures web traffic. I am assuming that LTE uses data to transmit calls as well (probably SIP) as everything is data these days, but it would be neat to see these packets and what they look like. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

No, calls don't work that way. They don't go through the same network interface as internet data, and they're treated completely differently by the modem. Phone networks are circuit-switched, not packet-switched like IP, so there aren't any "packets" to examine.

Comment: You're wrong, LTE does use IP packets for voice.